# GCC and makefile: Only show errors and warnings

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a makefile that compiles every .c file in my project. For each file, I get the whole compile command printed out to the shell, with all the options and flags. This is the example output for one file:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -O0 -dM -g -gdwarf-2 -mthumb
>   -fomit-frame-pointer -fverbose-asm -Wa,-ahlms=src/sim/sim_configuration.lst   -include ./lib/stm32core/stm32f2xx_conf.h -I . -I./lib/ARMStandardLibrary
>   -I./lib/LwIP -I./lib/LwIP/src/include -I./lib/LwIP/src/include -I./lib/LwIP/src/include/ipv4 -I./lib/LwIP/src/include/ipv6 -I./lib/FatFS -I./lib/stm32core -I./src -I./src/sim -I./src/sd -I./src/tftp src/sim/sim_configuration.c -o src/sim/sim_configuration.o

The problem is that various warnings get lost inside this whole mess of command outputs. Is there a way to *only* print the warnings and errors that appear (*not* the original command)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prepend the command with [the `@` symbol](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing).

If you rely on [built-in implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), you will have to make them explicit or, in your specific case, you could use:

```
.SILENT: *.o
```

for silencing all commands used for building to the `%.o` targets.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) using `@`, you can do `MAKEFLAGS += --quiet`. That will work for built-in rules as well.

Comment: Yes, but then **every** command in **every** rule will not be echoed.

Comment: As always, it's a trade off, but it handles built-in rules. In general, making built-in rules explicit is a very bad idea, so setting `MAKEFLAGS` may be a better method. Or not, of course.

Comment: Maybe the `.SILENT` solution is better?

Answer (score 24):

Execute `make` with the `-s` option. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make).

```
-s, --silent, --quiet
    Silent operation; do not print the commands as they are executed.
```

Answer (score 5):

You could always filter all the output from `stdout`, which should leave you with all the errors on `stderr`:

```
make 1>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `@` before a command to hide the it:

```
rule1:
  @gcc someting
```